# DFS Using Domain Alias

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

Client has SuperVeryExtraLong.com AD domain so a DFS namespace becomes `\\SuperVeryExtraLong.com\foo` with a minimum of 29 characters.  This is a problem with the 255 character path limit.

Is there a way to create a domain alias that can be used by DFS-R?

I have looked at creating a cname however that I'm unable to figure out how to get DFS to use this and am concerned about name resolution/site location issues down the road.  Would rather not rename AD just for this.
AD is 2008 R2, no Exchange.

Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and don't *ever* rename AD for anything. Ever.

Comment: I know using DFS cmdlets in Powershell, you can get around the *.local domain name when setting up the DFS namespace. New-DfsnRoot -TargetPath "\\Servername\SMBShare" -Type DomainV2 -Path "\\ABC\RootNamespaceName" I use that to setup a namespace.  However, in DFS Mgmt UI, the namespace is displayed as the full \\*.local\Namespace. I know your question is in reference to 2008 R2, but while the DFS cmdlets run only on WinServer 2012\Win8 computers and up, you can use them to manage DFS Namespaces hosted even on previous Windows Server versions: Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: In the DFS UI, you cannot setup a DFS namespace using the AD Domain alias.  That is why I mention using the Powershell cmdlets.

Comment: New-DfsnRoot -TargetPath "\\Servername\SMBShare" -Type DomainV2 -Path "\\ABC\RootNamespaceName"  -TargetPath is the path to your server hosting the share.  -Type DomainV2 means Server 2008 mode.  -Path is the name you want your DFS namespace to be, e.g., \\Contoso\Accounting.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it for DFS, but sounds like you should add an UPN on you Active Directory Domains and Trusts: that adds an "alias" for the domain, so DFS should be redirected properly.

Again, never tried it for DFS.

Comment: I get the UPN part, still don't see how to get DFS to work.